# How do I prevent a div container with absolute position to be cut off when the list rendered inside grows?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I'm creating a dropdown menu in React with an absolute position set, it's populated by a list of buttons, as soon as it grows my container gets cut off. I can see if I zoom it out that the element is rendered fine, it just overflows and it's hidden. I have tried to set `overflow: visible` but unfortunately it doesn not work, or I am doing something wrong here.
I can't seem to find a good solution for this issue.

How to work around it?

Thank you, here's my code:

```
  <div className={styles.Container} onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }}>
      <div className={menuClassNames} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <div className={styles.option}>
          <p>{menuLabel}</p>{" "}
          <div onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setIsOpen(false)
          }} className={styles.iconWrapper}>
            <Close />
          </div>
        </div>

        {menus.map((m, i) => {
          return <button key={i} className={styles.OptionButton} onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            handleMenuClick(m.onClick)
          }}>
          </button>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.Container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;

  .Menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;

    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 51, 76, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;

    width: 240px;
    overflow: auto;

    p {
      color: #123962;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    &.Open {
      display: block;
    }

    .option {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```